# как работать с RTMP из php?

Tags: php, curl, rtmp, hls, online-video

Сделал nginx с nginx_rtmp_module. С устройств на сервер вещаются live streaming по rtmp и так же их можно получить по hls.
Возможно ли работать с RTMP из PHP?
Для начала было бы хорошо хотя бы получить все трансляции что в данный момент ведутся при помощи php...